# Android: read window title resource id

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-titlebar, resource-id

I am trying to create a custom title layout but I'd still want to use the activity's original label text. Is there a way to reference the window title (label attribute) in my custom title xml? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by a custom title layout?

Comment: Like dis http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/CustomTitle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to override `Activity.onTitleChanged()` method. I've never tried this solution but it must work according to the Android source code.

Comment: OK - it works. A pure xml solution would be better but I am happy with this for now.

Comment: In theory, if a custom title contains a `TextView` with `android:id=@android:id/title` then it will be a pure xml solution. But it's only an assumption.

Comment: Right but the custom title has already overridden the original so this doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Have you tried this? I mean setting `TextView`'s id to `"@android:id/title"`?

Comment: Tried that. It doesn't display anything when placed into the title bar.

Comment: That's bad. Looks like bad design.

Comment: @e_x_p let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2476/discussion-between-pixie-and-e-x-p)